# Python / Pandas - Looping through a folder appending files to a data frame if they are in a second data frame

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am having a hard time doing something that seems somewhat simple:

Part I
Creating an empty dataframe to store my data

Part II
I am using python to iterate through a folder, and look for macro enable excel files

Part III
This is where I had a hard time -- Ideally I want to  see if 'i' is in the data frame "file_df"'s column "File_Name" then append it to the FileList data frame. Note: this column in the file_df data frame is just a list of the files I actually want to use from the folder.

```
   import pandas as pd
   import glob 
   import os

   #Part I
   FileList = pd.DataFrame(index=file_df.index, columns=['File_Name'])

   # Part II
   os.chdir(path)
   for i in glob.glob('*.xlsm'): # gives list of files from the folder

   # Part III
   if file_df[file_df['File_Name'].str.contains(i)]:
        FileList.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this

```
import pandas as pd
import os
str1 = "i"
fileList=[]
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path): # iterating over the files and sub folders
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(("*.xlsm")):  # finding a file with pdf extension
            a = os.path.join(subdir, file)   # if we find the file we extract its path

            filename = a.rsplit('/')[-1]  # gets us filename with extension
            if str1 in filename:
            fileList.append(filename)
```